# Case, group by , join on multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables `transaction` , `store` and `date`. A column in `store table` needs to be assigned values based on conditions and that new column needs to be used in  group by.

ASK is to find ` total sales across different banners for a particular time period.

i am using following query..

```
"""select sum(net_spend) as sales , d.fis_week_id, st.banner
    from  ( select s*,
    CASE  WHEN st.format IN ('S','S MINI','S HYPER') THEN 'S'
          WHEN st.format = 'CHECKERS' THEN 'CHECKERS'
          ELSE st.format END AS banner 
          from store_dim s) st
    from transaction_item_fct tr 
    inner join date_dim d on d.date_id = tr.date_id 
    inner join store_dim_c s on st.store_id = tr.store_id
    where d.fis_week_id >=201809 and d.fis_week_id<=201813
    and tr.store_id = st.store_id 
    group by st.banner, d.fis_week_id
```

"""

Where I am getting wrong?

Below is the fabricated tables' data

Transaction table-

```
store_id   week_id   net_spend
  1          12       345
  1          11       788
  2          13       556
  3          11       300
```

Store table

```
store_id   format
  1          S
  2          S MINI
  3          S Hyper
  4          Checker
```

Date table

```
week_id     fis_week_id
 11          201712
 12          201717
```

Result expected is

```
week_id     banner    spend
  11         S         888
  11         Hyper     666
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please provide a SQL Fiddle or DB Fiddle. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: There is a chance, that you many not need any subquery at all. So please try to provide a fiddle, for other to play with and give optimized (performant) query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question but I think this query will do what you want. You will need to change the `WHERE` condition on `d.fis_week_id` as appropriate for your needs, I have made it appropriate for the demo case I set up.

```
SELECT d.week_id, st.banner, SUM(t.net_spend) AS sales, d.fis_week_id
FROM date_dim d
LEFT JOIN transaction_item t ON t.week_id = d.week_id
JOIN (SELECT store_id,
             CASE WHEN format IN ('S', 'S MINI', 'S Hyper') THEN 'S'
                  WHEN format = 'Checker' THEN 'Checker'
                  ELSE format
                  END AS banner
      FROM store_dim s) st
    ON st.store_id = t.store_id
WHERE d.fis_week_id BETWEEN 201712 AND 201720
GROUP BY d.week_id, st.banner
```

I've expanded your demo data out a bit and created a test case at [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4e137/1):

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_item
    (`store_id` int, `week_id` int, `net_spend` int);

INSERT INTO transaction_item
    (`store_id`, `week_id`, `net_spend`)
VALUES (1, 12, 345), (1, 11, 788), (2, 13, 556), (3, 11, 300),
       (4, 11, 440), (4, 12, 123), (5, 11, 100), (6, 13, 444);

CREATE TABLE store_dim
    (`store_id` int, `format` varchar(7));

INSERT INTO store_dim
    (`store_id`, `format`)
VALUES (1, 'S'), (2, 'S MINI'), (3, 'S Hyper'), (4, 'Checker'), (5, 'Checker'), (6, 'Other');

CREATE TABLE date_dim
    (`week_id` int, `fis_week_id` int);

INSERT INTO date_dim
    (`week_id`, `fis_week_id`)
VALUES (11, 201712), (12, 201717), (13, 201720);
```

Output:

```
week_id     banner      sales   fis_week_id
11          Checker     540     201712
11          S           1088    201712
12          Checker     123     201717
12          S           345     201717
13          Other       444     201720
13          S           556     201720
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick .. it worked and got performance of the query increased too

Comment: Nick , I want to know one more thing about query execution. I mean the order of execution.. Here we are using subquery , so is it  processed for each row of primary query ?? Or subquery is processed and results are cached?

Comment: @SeemaMudgil the subquery should be processed once and then the results `JOIN`ed to the transaction table based on the `store_id` values. Only the `WHERE` clause will be evaluated per row of the result table.